# Android Studio doesn't see Partitions

Tags: android, linux, android-studio

I have dual boot with Windows 10 and Linux 18.1. I am running Android Studio on linux.
I have my android projects in Windows C drive, the problem is when I try to open the project Android Studio doesn't show the option to load the project from C drive (See Image below for reference).

[image]

Comment: You're using Linux, but the project is located in the Windows C drive? Have you tried moving the project to the linux's C drive, because that is what android is trying to look for

Comment: Yes I have tried, If I move the project to my home directory on the linux drive then the project loads. What I was looking for was, how to load the project from Windows C drive. Is that possible?